Windows Smart Screen - Blazor Static Web App
I am working on a simple Blazor Azure Static Web App.
I published it to Azure and now Edge shows the red unsafe site warning.
When I turn off Smart Screen it works fine
Will purchasing my own domain name rectify this?
Here is an example of an empty static-web-app (we have not published any code yet) and the same thing happens? why would it be unsafe whether we try one with a stock standard blazor WASM web app and another with nothing published yet ...



Can you please explain the issue in detail.

I created a boilerplate wasm (blazor) web application.
Then published this to a new static web app.
But when I browse to this new static web application Microsoft Edge shows a red page "This site has been reported as unsafe"
I have to turn SmartScreen off in Windows Settings to make this work.
It works fine using Chrome browser?

What is the version of your Blazor WASM?

Aha I have just created a new static web app and have not uploaded anything - no blazor was - nothing and we receive the same unsafe site report? Why would that happen when nothing was even published?

https://black-ocean-045738903.5.azurestaticapps.net/

only when we select to allow / show content do we receive the default "Congratulations on your new site!
Your site will be ready soon—please check back later." message

Can you share your initial error screen

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

ok i will update the question with the new blank site, we see same on several laptops both private and company laptops:

You are not deploying any code that's y you are seeing the default display page.

Ok..will check from my end and let you know.

as I said before, when we do deploy code it does the same it works fine when we click show unsafe content either way with or without code published.

Hi, could you submit your file hash to Microsoft for analysis. Here is a link on how to go about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-endpoint/admin-submissions-mde?view=o365-worldwide @DataWrangler1980

I am not getting any error.Able to deploy and see the default page.What is the version of the Blazor?

i do not even have to publish a blazor app

even after simply creating a new static web app i see the unsafe message as showin screenshots - no code even published - so it does not matter also tried the vanila web app with no framework and same story

I have purchase a custom domain and configured my site to use the custom domain, now the unsafe message for my specific site has disappeared, however when trying to sign in with github or aad I still get this error: This site has been reported as unsafe
Hosted by identity.5.azurestaticapps.net

trying to sign in with github. What does this mean?

It is working Microsoft must have fixed the issue with this unsafe single sign on provider:   "identity.5.azurestaticapps.net"
